# work with time datatype in ruby

Tags: ruby, time

Are there gems available to work with `SQL TIME`(00:00:00...23:59:59) in Ruby. Right now it is cast to a datetime object wich is definately not what I want. I want to check if a certain time is included in a timeframe.

My best solution sofar is to cast it to a integer in ruby(0...235959) and work against this, but I wonder if there are beter solutions out there.

I want to use it for a subscription application, where people can subscribe to notifications and say they want to receive them for example between 7:00 and 18:30

Answer (score 0):

In the most general case, that won't work without some pain. The value of "midnight plus 2 hours and 15 minutes" isn't determinate in the face of daylight savings time. On the morning of a change in the spring, "02:15AM" isn't a valid time.

You might be able to sidestep that issue by disallowing times between, say, midnight and 4:00 am.

If you're not using a database, you can store 24-hour times as strings in a canonical format. Canonical strings can be compared directly for equality and inequality, and you can do simple arithmetic with them by concatenating them with an arbitrary date and using Ruby's native Date methods.

Or you could build a class that implements whatever "time" interface you like.

Gems: ice_cube and tickle sound like they're targeting your problem space, but I haven't used them.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like the main issue here is the divide between the SQL time string format and Ruby's datetime object.

I think what you need are the [`DateTime#strftime`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-strftime) and [`DateTime#strptime`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime) methods.  For example, to go from a DateTime object `d` to the SQL string, you'd use `d.strftime('%H:%M:%S')`, and to go from the string `s` to a DateTime, you'd use `DateTime.strptime(s, '%H:%M:%S')`.

EDIT:
I know that.  I was saying that, since you can't do those calculations in the string format that sql uses, you can convert it to a DateTime or Time object and do something like this for your example of between 7:00 and 18:30:

```
time = DateTime.strptime(<sql output string>, '%H:%M:%S')
start_time, end_time = DateTime.strptime('07:00:00', '%H:%M:%S'), DateTime.strptime('18:30:00', '%H:%M:%S')

(start_time..end_time).cover? time
```

Comment: I am interested in doing calculations based on time, not formatting a string.